# How to detect if a variable follows a "false statement" for setting up dynamic numbered lists in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Pardon my horrid explanation skills. Very new to PHP.

So I'm building a dynamic numbered list on the left side of my page.
Each different task is put into it's own array (consisting of 'name' and 'content') and all tasks are put into an array consisting of those tasks and their details. The tasks and their ordered number and name will go in the sidebar on the left, and the content will be looped in on the right side of the page (If that wasn't clear enough, its a page with a left sidebar and a main content window to the right of that)

```html
$task0 = array('name' => 'Update status in CRM', 'content' => 'blargeyblarg');
$task1 = array('name' => "Pre Meeting Email:", 'content' => 'blargeyblarg2' );

$task2 = array('name' => "Welcome cover letter", 'content' => 'blargeyblarg3');

$task3 = array('name' => "Welcome email:", 'content' => 'blargeyblarg4');

$task4 = array('name' => "Initial Meeting Agenda", 'content' => 'blargeyblarg5');


$tasks = array($task0, $task1, $task2, $task3, $task4);
```

However, when trying to display the correct numbered order of the tasks in this list, I needed to created a statement to look for any 'names' of tasks that ended in ':' because they would be 'heading' tasks that would have slightly different stylings but would have the SAME number scheme as the tasks before it.

Basically, the list should read:

1,2,3,4,5

```html
<ul class="nav list-group">

   <?php foreach ($tasks as $i => $task) { ?>
    <?php
     $is_heading = ends_with($task["name"],":");
    ?>

    <li class="list-group-item" tabindex="-1">
     <a class="listgroupwrap" href="#g<?= ++$i?>">
     </a>
                    <span class="step-number-container"> <?= +$i ?>
                    </span>
                        <span class="btn-check">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </span>
     <!--<span class="step-checkbox"></span>-->

                            <span class="step-name"><?php echo $task["name"] ?>
                                </span>
                                    <span class="step-show-hide">

                                            <span class="btn">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
            </i>
                                            </span>
                                    </span>
    </li>

    <?php if (!$is_heading): ?>
     <li class="list-group-item step-heading" tabindex="-1">
     <a class="listgroupwrap" href="#g<?= $i +1 ?>">
     </a>
     <span class="step-number-container"> <?= $i?></span>
     <span class="step-name"><?php echo $task["name"] ?>
                                </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>



   <?php } ?>
```

However it is displaying

1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5

There are only supposed to be 5 tasks in total.

What am I doing wrong here, besides the obvious noobishness?

Comment: Your code has a reference to function "ends_with", but that's not a built-in PHP function. Where does that function come from? I think the problem is that $is_heading is always set to false, possibly because that function doesn't exist and is silently failing.

Comment: Ah, terribly sorry. I declared the ends_with variable in my functions.php file.  function ends_with($str, $suffix) {
    $length = strlen($suffix);
    if ($length == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return (substr($str, -$length) === $suffix);
}

Comment: The '!$is_heading' is meant to find tasks that are 'heading tasks' so instead of having the checkboxes and other html styles you see above....it just makes it bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rewrote answer in accordance with new information.**

After taking a look at the output, I see what you're talking about now. It's not that the loop is running twice for each task, but that, for certain tasks (i.e., non headers), you are outputting two rows per task.

The following gets output, regardless of header or not:

```
<li class="list-group-item" tabindex="-1">
    <a class="listgroupwrap" href="#g<?= ++$i?>"></a>
    <span class="step-number-container"> <?= +$i ?></span>
    <span class="btn-check">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </span>
    <!--<span class="step-checkbox"></span>-->
    <span class="step-name"><?php echo $task["name"] ?></span>
    <span class="step-show-hide">
            <span class="btn">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

This row gets output only if it's not a header:

```
<?php if (!$is_heading): ?>
    <li class="list-group-item step-heading" tabindex="-1">
        <a class="listgroupwrap" href="#g<?= $i +1 ?>"></a>
        <span class="step-number-container"> <?= $i?></span>
        <span class="step-name"><?php echo $task["name"] ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
    </li>
```

Two things. First, a quick note that the last `</li>` there should be inside that if statement.

Second, you'll need another if statement encompassing the first row, only outputting when if ($is_heading).

That should solve it.

Comment: I knew that ++ was manually increasing the variable, but essentially i just want the list to continue to 1. Count in numerical order 2. for each new task, increase the anchor +1. Since each anchor is "g1" or "g2" representing it's css ID.....i'm trying to have the PHP keep counting incrementally while still applying the styles to the 'header' tasks. Does that make sense?

Comment: Foreach will do that automatically. $i is being set to the array index for the value $task. As long as you don't modify $i within the foreach, $tasks[$i] === $task. There's no need to modify the variable.

Comment: Also, setting it to the array key is kind of what I wanted to do. Except I need to increase that by 1...since the key will start at 0. Before I used "$i + 1" which works fine on the non-header tasks.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That makes sense, but you'll want to use a different variable than $i. The foreach statement is modifying it after each loop, causing interference.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far guys. I changed the $i to $number (declared as $i +1). This is what it looks like. http://imgur.com/khe7sFb

Comment: I also cant figure out why the tasks are duplicating themselves. It is creating 8 tasks when there should only be 5.

Comment: From that image, only the non-header tasks are duplicated. It definitely seems related.

Comment: I can definitely see that too. It's quite frustrating. What do you think the best way to not have them duplicate tasks, but still continue their numerical order?

Comment: I essentially need to add a class to the element when it is NOT a heading, but after reading through some S.O. threads thats quite a big security risk for whatever data is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kal, you really helped me out!